# Bulk insert into SQL Server 2005 issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I've tried bulk insert but I can't get it right. I have a table schema that starts with an id and a few more columns then I need to skip a column. Whats the proper way to assign the columns to each one from a csv?

Thanks

EDIT:

MY Code:

```
BULK INSERT datadb
from 'C:\datainsert.csv'
WITH
(
FIRSTROW=2,
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

The errors is talking about my first column being a different datatype since I have an ID column

Comment: Have you specified a `FORMATFILE` parameter? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

Comment: Normally, the `BULK INSERT` just does this - inserts a large bulk of data, into a **staging table** that looks exactly like the data you're importing. Once you've done that - *then* you can apply the data to the actual real tables and do things like skip a column etc.

Comment: @marc_s The staging table idea worked! I should have thought of that before! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marc_s nailed it.  I created a staging table and bulk loaded to that one.  Then did a select into from it into my existing table.  Thanks Marc_s!

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the same and it is working without any issues.

Please post the metadata of your table and csv file, so that I will get a chance to find the issue.